# Configuring maxThreads for Apache websocket component

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, jetty

I'm trying to setup my first websocket using Apache Camel in a Spring Boot environment.

So far so good, I was able to easily declare a route, a very basic one indeed, to test it out.

```
@Component
public class RoutesNotification extends RouteBuilder {

    protected static final String ECHO = "websocket://echo";

    @Override
    public void configure() {

        from(ECHO)
            .transform().simple("${body}${body}")
            .to(ECHO);
    }

}
```

Or so I thought.

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Insufficient threads: max=9 < needed(acceptors=2 + selectors=8 + request=1)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:414)
```

Sure enough, I looked around, and it appears that both *Jetty* and the Camel *websocket* component (which, incidently, uses an embedded Jetty) allow to set a custom number of threads with the **maxThreads** options as described there : http://camel.apache.org/websocket.html

Problem is, I have not been able to figure out how I should configure this option for the component.

In the past, I have mainly used the *servlet* component, which I customized like this :

```
restConfiguration()
        .component("servlet")
        // Swagger
        .contextPath(Urls.General.API_URL).apiContextPath(Urls.General.SWAGGER_URL).apiProperty("api.title", "{{name}}")
        .apiProperty("api.version", "{{version}}").apiProperty("cors", "true").apiContextRouteId("doc-api")
        // Binding mode pour les formats de message JSON ou XML
        .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off)
        // Preflight request
        .enableCORS(true) // Cross-Origin Resource Sharing
        .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Range, X-Custom-Header, JWT")
        .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, CONNECT, PATCH")
        .corsHeaderProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
        .corsHeaderProperty("Pragma", "no-cache").corsHeaderProperty("Expires", "0, value");
```

But of course, a websocket is no REST, and I didn't find the equivalent for this component.
I tried this, also :

```
getContext()
        .getComponent("websocket")
        .createComponentConfiguration()
        .setParameter("maxThreads", 200);
```

But

1. It didn't work out
2. createComponentConfiguration() and setParameter() are deprecated anyway

I'm at a loss here.

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: That warning is a server level message, the ThreadPool configuration applies to all requests, regardless of servlet or websocket or REST.   Its specified before a webapp even exists or is attempted to be created.  How do you configure your server level component?

Comment: Do you have anything in your project configuring `org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent` yet?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JoakimErdfelt.
No, I don't have anything configuring the component, in fact that's exactly what I've been unable to find in the official Camel documentation (not for lack of searching). I want to configure the maxThreads attribute, which the *websocket* component does expect, according to the page I linked.
Most of the articles and tutorials are about XML configuration, which I don't use.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is fairly simple: configure the Component Option on the component, and add it to the context. You were very close to a solution actually!

```
   WebsocketComponent websocketComponent = new WebsocketComponent();
   websocketComponent.setMaxThreads(10);
   getContext().addComponent("websocket", websocketComponent);
```